# how to get relation field with condition

Tags: php, wordpress, podscms

When we want to get some relation field we do

```
$pod = pods( 'pod_name', get_the_id() );
$related = $pod->field( 'relationship_field' );
```

and I get list of results array 1, 2 ...
but I need to get `relationship_field` where `name="some_name"`. How can I do that?

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to do something like `$params = array('where' => "name='some_name'"); $result = $relatated->find($params);`

Comment: name is related field in this case and this queery will throw error unknown colomun

Answer (score 1):

The following will retrieve the related field named `relationship_field` if the related post has a title equal to `some_name`:

```
$pod = pods('pod_name', get_the_ID());
$params = array(
  'WHERE' => "relationship_field.post_title = 'some_name'",
);

$related = $pod->find($params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're example was right, but with a minor tweak this will be more useful as an example:

```php
// get the pod record based on current post ID
$pod = pods( 'pod_name', get_the_ID() );

$params = array(
    // be sure to sanitize the value going in, if it's dynamic
    'where' => 'relationship_field.post_title = "Some title"'
);

// find records that match $params
$pod->find( $params );

// loop through records found
while ( $pod->fetch() ) {
    // do something with $pod->field( 'field_name' )
    // or $pod->display( 'field_name' )
}
```